# What UI element in Cocoa Touch is this?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I see this in the mail application on my iPod Touch and I'm wondering if this is a UI element.  If not, how can I reproduce it?

[image]

Comment: An UIButton probably? Maybe just a custom button with the arrow drawn and then you modify the text on the button itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the desktop, that'd be called a "token field." They first appeared in Mail.app, and eventually became part of the AppKit framework. [Documentation here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TokenField_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006555-CH1-SW1)

It should be pretty easy to reproduce that look in Cocoa Touch. In Cocoa Touch, every view is backed by a Core Animation layer, and layers have a `cornerRadius` attribute. Set that attribute to half the height of the field to create rounded ends. You can set a background color if you're okay with a flat appearance, or you can draw a subtle gradient to give a more convex appearance.

Of course, you only need to do all that if you want a reusable view where you can set the text and so forth. If you only need a few of these for custom buttons or something, it might be easier to just draw them in your favorite drawing program.

Another possibility is to use a third party control, such as any of:

- [TITokenField](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/titokenfield)
- [JSTokenField](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jstokenfield)
- COTokenField (part of [COPeoplePickerViewController](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/copeoplepickerviewcontroller))

Answer (score 0):

If it is in UIKit you can use [UIKit-Artwork-Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor) to retrieve it. Good luck searching :)