# How to implement tag functionality like tumblr

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to implement tagging functionality like tumblr. I tried with UITextfield and added UIButtons for tags_name in textfield.

1. How to select tag on first back and delete it on second back?
2. How tags should be added in multiple lines in UITextfield?

please suggest  any solution for this functionality.
here is the code how I added buttons in UItextfield with array.

```
    for (count_value = 1; count_value<=[textfieldarray count]; count_value++)
    {
        UIButton *button_dish = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button_dish setTag:count_value];
        [button_dish.layer setOpacity:0.5];
        [button_dish.layer setCornerRadius:4.0f];
        [button_dish setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [button_dish setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
        [button_dish setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
        [button_dish setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 4, 8)];
        [button_dish.titleLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        [button_dish.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Eau-SansBold" size:12]];
        [button_dish setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
        [button_dish setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];
        [button_dish setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button_dish setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        [button_dish setTitle:textfieldarray[count_value-1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        CGSize expected_Size1 = [textfieldarray[count_value-1] sizeWithFont:button_dish.titleLabel.font constrainedToSize:button_dish.frame.size lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];


        [button_dish addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonactionmethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        left_view_length1 = left_view_length1+expected_Size1.width+16+12;

        [iconview1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, left_view_length1, 24)];
        [button_dish setFrame:CGRectMake(x_cordinate1, 2, expected_Size1.width+16, 20)];
        x_cordinate1 = x_cordinate1+expected_Size1.width+16+12;

        [iconview1 addSubview:button_dish];
        [textfield1 setLeftView:iconview1];
    }
```

Here is the sample reference image for tumblr tag,
1st image shows selection of button on first back.
2nd image shows multiple line tags.

[image]

[image]

Please give me some reference or hint.

Comment: I'm against down voting this question. I would have asked the same thing a few days ago but hadn't experimented with code yet. This guy has sample code and screenshots. It's a valid question.

Comment: Even i don't know, on which basis people down voting question? If question doesn't show any effort then it will be. but here ? :-(

Answer (score 0):

That'd be called a "**token field**." They first appeared in Mail.app, and eventually became part of the AppKit framework. [Documentation here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TokenField_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006555-CH1-SW1)

It should be pretty easy to reproduce that look in Cocoa Touch. In Cocoa Touch, every view is backed by a Core Animation layer, and layers have a `cornerRadius` attribute according to your UI. Set that attribute to half the height of the field to create rounded ends. You can set a background color if you're okay with a flat appearance, or you can draw a subtle gradient to give a more convex appearance.

Of course, you only need to do all that if you want a reusable view where you can set the text and so forth. If you only need a few of these for custom buttons or something, it might be easier to just draw them in your favorite drawing program.

Another possibility is to use a third party control, such as any of:

- [TITokenField](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/titokenfield)
- [JSTokenField](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jstokenfield)
- [RMStokenview](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/rmstokenview)
- COTokenField (part of [COPeoplePickerViewController](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/copeoplepickerviewcontroller))

Reference from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10859692/1597744) Answer.